# E-mail confirmation implementation in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have created a Django app. I have a registration page(simple HTML form) in the app,and it has an e-mail field while registering. Now i wanted to implement an email verification when the user registers. Like sending an email to the user (to email given in registration form). By googling i found there is a Django method 'send_email' which can be used for the above. But being a Django newbie, i was not able to understand the changes and functions to be created for doing so. Can somebody help me to do this or point some tutorials which would help me out. Or is there any other way to implement this other than the 'send_email' method of Django. Any help would be appreciated

**VIEWS.PY**

```
def registrationForm(request):
    if request.method == "POST":  
        firstName = request.POST.get("firstName")
        lastName = request.POST.get("lastName")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        sex = request.POST.get("sex")
        birthday = request.POST.get("birthday")
        print request.POST.get("sex")
        UniversityDetails(firstName=firstName,lastName=lastName,email=email,password=password,sex=sex,birthday=birthday).save()
        return render_to_response('registrationForm.html')
    return render_to_response("registrationForm.html")

def login(request):
    if request.POST:            
        email=request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        print email
        print password
        user = UniversityDetails.objects.filter(email=email,password=password)
        print user
        if(not user):
            return render_to_response("registrationForm.html",{'invalid': True })
        else:
            return render_to_response("login.html")
    return render_to_response("registrationForm.html")
```

**registrationform.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>

<title>
Login/Registration Page
</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

   //Created / Generates the captcha function    
    function DrawCaptcha()
    {
        var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';
        var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';       
        var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var f = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var g = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' '+ f + ' ' + g;
        document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code
    }

    // Validate the Entered input aganist the generated security code function   
    function ValidCaptcha(){
        var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
        var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
        if (str1 == str2) return true;        
        return false;

    }

    // Remove the spaces from the entered and generated code
    function removeSpaces(string)
    {
        return string.split(' ').join('');
    }

    </script>
<body onload="DrawCaptcha();">

<div align="center">
<form name="userInputForm" method="POST" id="myFormid" action="http://10.1.0.90:8080/login/">
<div style="float:left;width:100%;">
  <p style="float:left;margin-right:10px;width:auto;"><label style="float:left;">Email id</label><br/> <input type="text" name="username" size="25" /></p>
  <p style="float:left;margin-right:10px;width:auto;"><label style="float:left;">Password</label><br/><input type="password" name="password" size="25" />

{% if invalid %}
    Mismatch in your email/password. 
{% endif %}

</p>

 </div> 
    <p style="clear:both;float:left;"><input type="submit" value="Log in" /></p> 
</div>
</form><
<script type="text/javascript">
function userCheck(){
    /*document.getElementById('myFormid').action = "http://10.1.0.90:8080/login/";
    if ((document.userInputForm.username.value.length==0)) */
}
</script>
<form name ="myform"  method="POST" id='FormID'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>First name</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="firstName" value=""  maxlength="100" />
<b id="firstNameID" style="font-family:Times New Roman;color:#B4045F;font-size:14px;">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Last name</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="lastName" value="" maxlength="100" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>E-mail</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" maxlength="100" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="100"  />
<b id="passwordID" style="font-family:Times New Roman;color:#B4045F;font-size:14px;">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender:</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Birthday</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="birthday" id='datepicker' value="" maxlength="100" />
</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtCaptcha" 
            style="background-image:url(1.jpg); text-align:center; border:none;
            font-weight:bold; font-family:Modern" />
        <input type="button" id="btnrefresh" value="Refresh" onclick="DrawCaptcha();" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtInput"/>    
    </td>

<td> <br> <br>
<input type="button" value="Sign Up" onClick="isEmpty();"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
function isEmpty(){
    if  ((document.myform.firstName.value.length==0)) 
        {
        document.getElementById('firstNameID').innerHTML = 'Please fill this field';
        return true;
        }
    else if ((document.myform.password.value.length==0)) 
        {
        document.getElementById('passwordID').innerHTML = 'Please fill this field';
        return true;
        }
    else if (! ValidCaptcha())
        {
            alert("Captcha entered wrong");
        }

    else 
        { 
        document.getElementById('FormID').action = "http://10.1.0.90:8080/registrationForm/";
        document.getElementById('FormID').submit();
        return false; 
        }
}
</script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Check the Django documentation: <a href="http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email"> Sending e-mail </a>.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) app.  You can find more documentation and tutorials through Google.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Philip. I have already implemented the registration page in html. My need is sending an email confirming the user registration. Is it possible to do  email verification functionality alone with simple registration form i created.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use [Signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/)

like [django-registration](http://code.google.com/p/django-registration/)